# Theory of reality by Ramanujan

Tags: mathematicians

I am reading the Book **"The man who knew Infinity"** by Robert Kanigel.In it, in the second chapter **"Ranging with delight"**, page: 66, he says:

> Later  in England, Ramanujan would build Theory of Reality around Zero and infinity, though his friends never quite figured out what he was getting at. Zero, it seemed, represented Absolute Reality. Infinity, or $\infty$, was the myriad manifestations of that reality. Their mathematical product, $\infty$ $\times$ 0, was not one numbers but all numbers, each of which corresponded to individual acts of Creation.

I am interested to know what is this Theory of Reality all about.

Thank you.

Comment: It was later superseded by the Theory of Everything.